# How to fix "error: unknown file system" on all available partitions

Tags: grub2, windows-7

I've had a running problem with removing Linux from my Windows 7 laptop. Initially, it was installed as a dual-boot, and worked well. To remove, I deleted the partitions on my laptop. This removed `grub`, and I was left with needing to enter:

```
set root=... 
set prefix=... 
insmod normal 
normal
```

each restart. I didn't restore the Windows boot-loader and have since re-partitioned my drive.

Now, upon reaching the command prompt screen, an `ls` query shows`hd0`, with three partitions, but none of them have a recognizable boot-loader as each returns with `error: unknown file system`.

Booting from a Windows 7 rescue disk doesn't seem to work, as it sends me to the same command prompt terminal.

All I'm looking to do is restore the boot-loader, either `grub` or Windows 7. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

boot Windows 7 rescue disk. When command prompt appear type:

```
BootRec.exe /fixmbr
```

or

```
BootRec.exe /fixboot
```